# Export to excel in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 8 reports and when exporting to excel I need all the reports in a single excel sheet.
Eg: Report 1 in sheet 1 of excel
    Report 2 in sheet 2 of excel likeewise

Is this possible????

Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a bit fiddly but you can.

If you create an empty report and populate it with sub-report components in rectangles (one for each of the eight reports you wish to generate). Set each rectange to start a new page and this should produce an eight sheet Excel workbook with one tab per report.

Comment: +1, although it does require a bit of rewriting existing reports.

Comment: But what if these reports are scheduled differently?? Eg: Report 1 is a daily report, Report 2 is a monthly report, Report 3 is an annual report??? Is it still possible???

Comment: Yes there's no reason why not. For example if the reports are to be produced for yesterday (daily) last month (monthly) and last year (yearly) then you could paramaterise the report based on the current day and calculate the appropriate parameters for each sub-report either within the SQL or with hidden parameters.